# Calling asyncio.sleep() seems to modify my object

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have an asynchronous `request()` function which mocks calling some API. I create a bunch of tasks that call this function with different parameters and await them. Everything works fine except when `await asyncio.sleep()` is added to the `request()` function. Adding this sleep call seems to modify the `request()` function's params dictionary! There really isn't a way around not awaiting `asyncio.sleep()` if I am to implement some kind of throttling.

```
"""Async API wrapper"""
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def request(params):
    print(f'params before:  {params}')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    print(f'params after:  {params}')
    return {'success': True, 'data': []}

async def get_resource(endpoint, start=0, filter_id=0, params={}):
    params['limit'] = 10
    params['start'] = start
    if filter_id:
        params['filter_id'] = filter_id

    r = await request(params)

    if r["success"]:
        return r
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'Request to /{endpoint} with {params} was not successful.')  

async def get_bulk_resource():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession():
        res = []
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(get_resource(endpoint='users', start=start)) for start in range(1, 101)]
        for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
            r = await task 
            res += r["data"]

    return res

lst = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_bulk_resource())
...
```

Printing the params before and after the sleep call, they are fine right before the sleep call:

```
params before:  {'limit': 10, 'start': 1}
params before:  {'limit': 10, 'start': 2}
params before:  {'limit': 10, 'start': 3}
...
params before:  {'limit': 10, 'start': 100}
```

While following asyncio.sleep(), the pagination value gets set to the last page for every task's execution of this coroutine:

```
params after:  {'limit': 10, 'start': 100}
params after:  {'limit': 10, 'start': 100}
params after:  {'limit': 10, 'start': 100}
...
params after:  {'limit': 10, 'start': 100}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem stems from the fact that `get_resource()` can take the request parameters either as separate arguments or as a dictionary in the `params` argument.

The problem with my implementation is that the default value for `params`, set to an empty dict, only creates this empty dict once and reuses it between subsequent calls, as opposed to creating a new one every call.

Explicitly declaring a new params dict to hold my parameters in completely solves this problem:

```
async def get_resource(endpoint, start=0, filter_id=0, params=None):
    if not params:
        params = {}
    params['limit'] = 10
    params['start'] = start
    if filter_id:
        params['filter_id'] = filter_id

    r = await _request(params)
    ...
```